# Generally quadratic convex problem with one non-convex term

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

How would you approach a standard convex quadratic problem  with convex constraints but one non-convex term ? Say $|x|^{0.4}$.

$$\min_x \frac{1}{2} x^{T}Qx + g^Tx + c^T \mathrm{sign}(x) |x|^{0.4}  $$
subject to $$Ax\leq b$$

Where $|\cdot|, \mathrm{sign}()$ are element-wise.

Is there any other way to solve the problem within convex framework ? What`s the best way to approximate if the dimensions are large ?

This is similar to [Reformulate a strictly convex QP problem containing absolute value term](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28035/reformulate-a-strictly-convex-qp-problem-containing-absolute-value-term) but here there is a power term.